# sum field values if they meet conditions

Tags: javascript, pdf, foxit

I am attempting to sum a number of field values but only if a condition associated with those filed values is met. For example:

I have a PDF form with several number value fields. Each of those number fields is accompanied by a choice in status. I simply want to add all of the number fields of the same status. Here is the code I tried and thought was working but it seems that if a status is changed on a Field previously added, it fails to work.  For example, if I add Field1, Field2 and Field4 because they are the same status but I go back and change Field2's status to something different, it stops working:

```
// field names
var cTotal1 = "Day1Pd1Total";
var cTotal2 = "Day1Pd2Total";
var cTotal3 = "Day1Pd3Total";
var cTotal4 = "Day1Pd4Total";
var cTotal5 = "Day1Pd5Total";
var cTotal6 = "Day1Pd6Total";
var cStatus1 = "Day1Pd1Status";
var cStatus2 = "Day1Pd2Status";
var cStatus3 = "Day1Pd3Status";
var cStatus4 = "Day1Pd4Status";
var cStatus5 = "Day1Pd5Status";
var cStatus6 = "Day1Pd6Status";
// get conditonal field values
var vStatus1 = this.getField(cStatus1).value;
var vStatus2 = this.getField(cStatus2).value;
var vStatus3 = this.getField(cStatus3).value;
var vStatus4 = this.getField(cStatus4).value;
var vStatus5 = this.getField(cStatus5).value;
var vStatus6 = this.getField(cStatus6).value;
// get field values base on condition
if(vStatus1 == "1"){
var vTotal1 = this.getField(cTotal1).value;
}else{
var vTotal1 = "";
}
if(vStatus2 == "1"){
var vTotal2 = this.getField(cTotal2).value;
}else{
var vTotal2 = "";
}
if(vStatus3 == "1"){
var vTotal3 = this.getField(cTotal3).value;
}else{
var vTotal3 = "";
}
if(vStatus4 == "1"){
var vTotal4 = this.getField(cTotal4).value;
}else{
var vTotal4 = "";
}
if(vStatus5 == "1"){
var vTotal5 = this.getField(cTotal5).value;
}else{
var vTotal5 = "";
}
if(vStatus6 == "1"){
var vTotal6 = this.getField(cTotal6).value;
}else{
var vTotal6 = "";
} 
// clear result value
event.value = "";
// add values
var FLPTotal = vTotal1 + vTotal2 + vTotal3 + vTotal4 + vTotal5 + vTotal6;
event.value = FLPTotal;
```

How do I get this script to recalculate when there are changes?  This is also in a PDF file.

Edit:  Further testing shows that the running order appears to be the issue.  vTotal1 will add successfully to vTotal2 and then to vTotal3 as long as they are populated in that order.  vTotal1 will not sum with vTotal3.  How do I sum the fields in any order?

Comment: It seems like an array may solve my problem, but I just am not clear on how to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am not exactlly sure why you have created multiple variables for each field.  Would something like this work?

```
var FLPTotal = 0;
```

Then for if one of the conditions is met you just add the value to it.

```
FLPTotal += this.getField(cTotal3).value;
```

If it returns as a string you could do.

```
FLPTotal += parseInt(this.getField(cTotal3).value);
```

The following would add up all the values of the cTotals.

```
// field names
var cTotal1 = "Day1Pd1Total";
var cTotal2 = "Day1Pd2Total";
var cTotal3 = "Day1Pd3Total";
var cTotal4 = "Day1Pd4Total";
var cTotal5 = "Day1Pd5Total";
var cTotal6 = "Day1Pd6Total";
var cStatus1 = "Day1Pd1Status";
var cStatus2 = "Day1Pd2Status";
var cStatus3 = "Day1Pd3Status";
var cStatus4 = "Day1Pd4Status";
var cStatus5 = "Day1Pd5Status";
var cStatus6 = "Day1Pd6Status";
// get conditional field values
var vStatus1 = this.getField(cStatus1).value;
var vStatus2 = this.getField(cStatus2).value;
var vStatus3 = this.getField(cStatus3).value;
var vStatus4 = this.getField(cStatus4).value;
var vStatus5 = this.getField(cStatus5).value;
var vStatus6 = this.getField(cStatus6).value;
// Add total variable
var FLPTotal = 0;
// get field values base on condition
if(vStatus1 == "1"){
FLPTotal += parseInt(this.getField(cTotal1).value);
}
if(vStatus2 == "1"){
FLPTotal += parseInt(this.getField(cTotal2).value);
}
if(vStatus3 == "1"){
FLPTotal += parseInt(this.getField(cTotal3).value);
}
if(vStatus4 == "1"){
FLPTotal += parseInt(this.getField(cTotal4).value);
}
if(vStatus5 == "1"){
FLPTotal += parseInt(this.getField(cTotal5).value);
}
if(vStatus6 == "1"){
FLPTotal += parseInt(this.getField(cTotal6).value);
}
// clear result value and set result value
event.value = "";
event.value = FLPTotal;
```

Tell me if this works.

Comment: I did not even think of it like this! I have been wracking my brain on this as I am also trying to learn JavaScript while trying to complete a high profile project.  The only issue I ran into is that some of my values have decimals.  So, I think the correct solution for that is to use 'parseFloat' instead of 'parseInt'.  Thank you!

Comment: I didn't think of there being decimals.  But I'm glad you figured out from there!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but if you want it concise, and assume that the values of all fields are secured (e.g. no undefined), then you may use

```
    Object.values(some object)
```

to make values of fields an array. And then it will be the inner product of two arrays: one comes from the slice for the portion "vStatus" and one from "cTotal".

Math.js may be a valid external library to resolve inner products concisely.

[Example of Object.values lies here (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```
    const object1 = {
      a: 'somestring',
      b: 42,
      c: false
    };

    console.log(Object.values(object1));
    // expected output: Array ["somestring", 42, false]
```

Comment: I am afraid I do not see how this fits my scenario.  I am not clear on how to create arrays from the data I have.,

Answer (score 0):

Try to create input and declare it as object in your **js** file and try use this object inside your **if statement** case to include the result. Then use it outside **if statement** globaly and tell me if it's works.

```js
let  vTotal1_val=document.querySelector("#inpt-first-val")
let  vTotal2_val=document.querySelector("#inpt-second-val")

if(case1 === true){
   let vTotal1 = this.getField(cTotal4).value;
   vTotal1_val.value=vTotal1
}
if(case2 === true){
   let vTotal2 = this.getField(cTotal4).value;
   vTotal2_val.value=vTotal2
}
let result =Number(vTotal1_val.value)+Number(vTotal2_val.value)
console.l(result)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="inpt-first-val" hidden>
  <input type="text" id="inpt-second-val" hidden>
    
</body>
</html>
```